# Apply KNN from small supervised dataset to large unsupervised dataset in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I have trained and tested a KNN model on a small supervised dataset of about 200 samples in Python. I would like to apply these results to a much larger unsupervised dataset of several thousand samples.

My question is: is there a way to fit the KNN model using the small supervised dataset, and then change the K-value for the large unsupervised dataset? I do not want to overfit the model by using the low K-value from the smaller dataset but am unsure how to fit the model and then change the K-value in Python.

Is this possible using KNN? Is there some other way to apply KNN to a much larger unsupervised dataset?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Provide some data for your question. Help community to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend actually fitting a KNN model on your larger dataset a couple of different times, each time using a different value for `k`. For each of those models you could then calculate the [Silhouette Score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html).

Compare the various silhouette scores and choose for your final value of `k` (number of clusters) the value that you used for your highest scoring model.

As an example, here's some code I used to do this for myself last year:

```
from sklearn import mixture
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


## A list of the different numbers of clusters (the 'n_components' parameter) with 
## which we will run GMM.
number_of_clusters = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

## Graph plotting method
def makePlot(number_of_clusters, silhouette_scores):
    # Plot the each value of 'number of clusters' vs. the silhouette score at that value
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 6))
    ax.set_xlabel('GMM - number of clusters')
    ax.set_ylabel('Silhouette Score (higher is better)')
    ax.plot(number_of_clusters, silhouette_scores)

    # Ticks and grid
    xticks = np.arange(min(number_of_clusters), max(number_of_clusters)+1, 1.0)
    ax.set_xticks(xticks, minor=False)
    ax.set_xticks(xticks, minor=True)
    ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='both')
    yticks = np.arange(round(min(silhouette_scores), 2), max(silhouette_scores), .02)
    ax.set_yticks(yticks, minor=False)
    ax.set_yticks(yticks, minor=True)
    ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='both')

## Graph the mean silhouette score of each cluster amount.
## Print out the number of clusters that results in the highest
## silhouette score for GMM.
def findBestClusterer(number_of_clusters):
    silhouette_scores = []
    for i in number_of_clusters:
        clusterer = mixture.GMM(n_components=i) # Use the model of your choice here
        clusterer.fit(<your data set>) # enter your data set's variable name here
        preds = clusterer.predict(<your data set>)
        score = silhouette_score(<your data set>, preds)
        silhouette_scores.append(score)

    ## Print a table of all the silhouette scores
    print("")
    print("| Number of clusters | Silhouette score |")
    print("| ------------------ | ---------------- |")
    for i in range(len(number_of_clusters)):
        ## Ensure printed table is properly formatted, taking into account
        ## amount of digits (either one or two) in the value for number of clusters.
        if number_of_clusters[i] <= 9:
            print("| {number}                  | {score:.4f}           |".format(number=number_of_clusters[i], 
                                                                        score=round(silhouette_scores[i], 4)))
        else:
            print("| {number}                 | {score:.4f}           |".format(number=number_of_clusters[i], 
                                                                        score=round(silhouette_scores[i], 4)))


    ## Graph the plot of silhoutte scores for each amount of clusters
    makePlot(number_of_clusters, silhouette_scores)

    ## Find and print out the cluster amount that gives the highest 
    ## silhouette score.
    best_silhouette_score = max(silhouette_scores)
    index_of_best_score = silhouette_scores.index(best_silhouette_score)
    ideal_number_of_clusters = number_of_clusters[index_of_best_score]
    print("")
    print("Having {} clusters gives the highest silhouette score of {}.".format(ideal_number_of_clusters,
                                                                                round(best_silhouette_score, 4)))

findBestClusterer(number_of_clusters)
```

Please note that in my example, I used a [GMM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html) model instead of KNN, but you should be able to slightly modify the `findBestClusterer()` method to use whatever clustering algorithm you wish. In this method you will also specify your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

In machine learning there are two broad types of learners, namely eager learners (Decision trees, neural nets, svms...) and lazy learners such as `KNN`. In fact, `KNN` doesn't do any learning at all. It just stores the "labeled" data you have and then uses it to perform inference such that it computes how similar the new sample (unlabeled) is, to all of the samples in the data that it has stored (labeled data). Then based on majority voting of the `K` nearest instances (`K` nearest neighbours hence the name) of the new sample, it will infer it's class/value.

Now to get to your question, "training" the `KNN` has nothing to do with the `K` itself, so when performing inference feel free to use whatever `K` gives the best result for you.